# Yaml input perl eternal looping issue

Tags: perl

$description is Input from a yaml file of format

```
main_key:
 -
  key1:value2
  key2:value2
 -
  key1:value1
  key2:value2
```

Basically that is a hash of array of hashes.

I input $description and process the inner hash as follows:

```
while (  my ( $mod, $defined )  = each %{ $description } ) {
  my $index = 0;
  foreach ( @{ $defined } ) {
    while ( my ( $key, $value )  = each %{ $_ } ) {
         process ( $key, $mod, $description, $index );
    }
  $index = $index + 1;
  }
}
```

When certain 'keyword' is used as a key I replace add more key,value pairs to the inner hash
function1() and function2() return a hash pointer.

```
sub process {
      my ( $key, $mod, $description, $index ) = @_; 
      my $parameters;
      if ( $key eq 'keyword' ) {
             $parameters = function1( );
      }
      else {
             $parameters = function2( );
      }
      $description->{$mod}[$index] = { %$parameters, %{$description->{$mod}[$index]} };
}
```

The issue here is that "while ( my ( $key, $value )  = each %{ $_ } )" in the main code runs forever, using the same key and value over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.  Don't do that.

Never modify a hash while looping over it.  From [perldoc -f each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

> If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it,
>   entries may be skipped or duplicated--so don't do that.

The general pattern is to build up the list of modifications, and then make them after the end of the loop. You can, of course, embed that sequence in an outer loop that iterates over the hash until there are no more modifications that need to be made.

Comment: I did however make a copy of the hash and try to modify the copy instead. Same result. I check to make sure the HASH references pointed to separate memory. Basically I passed $description_copy (pointed to different mem and copy of the original description to the process function

Answer (score 1):

This refactoring of your code works fine. I have rewritten `process` to do all that is necessary for the innermost hashes. I have named these `$item` as I don't know what they are supposed to represent. Please amend this to something more descriptive.

There never was any reason to pass all those parameters, as the values of `$description`, `$mod`, and `$index` were only used to locate the hash in question using `$description->{$mod}[$index]` so it may as well have been passed directly as a reference, which is what I do. In addition, because `process` now loops over the array contents there is no need to pass `$key` either, so the subroutine now has just one parameter.

Each element of `$item` is examined, and the new hash of data to be added for that element is obtained from `function1` or `function2` as appropriate and pushed onto `@params` instead of being inserted straight away.

Once all the new values have been established, they are all added into `$item` and the process is complete.

```
for my $defined (values %$description) {
  process($_) for @$defined;
}

sub process {
  my ($item) = @_;
  my @params;

  for my $key (keys %$item) {
    push @params, $key eq 'keyword' ? function1() : function2();
  }

  for my $params (@params) {
    @{$item}{keys %$params} = values %{$params};
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I need some time to integrate this in my code and will get back to you. It seems though that the major difference here is that the process is modifying at hash level rather than passing in individual keys at a time to the process. We are still modifying the hash "description" that we are woking on while looping on it.

Comment: @evolution: Yes, the *contents* of `$description` are being modified. Each of the hashes in the hash of arrays is passed by reference to `process` where it is modified. The main difference is that the required modifications are accumulated in `@params` and applied *after* the subroutine has examined all the keys. This is different from your code where new elements were being added as each key was examined, causing the infinite loop.